# Find number of times a number is followed by a larger number in a list

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have this function to find the number of times a number is followed by a larger number in a list. Is there another more "pythonic" way this could be done? I am using Python 3.7.0.

Thanks in advance.

```
def find_greater_numbers(arr):
    count = 0
    i = 0
    j = 1
    while i < len(arr):
        while j < len(arr):
            if arr[j] > arr[i]:
                count += 1
            j+=1
        j = i+1
        i+=1
    return count

find_greater_numbers([6,1,2,7]]) # returns 4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit unclear if you mean immediately followed, or followed at any later index

In the first case, this one liner:

```
sum(x < y for x,y in zip(arr[:-1],arr[1:])) # answer is 2
```

In the second, this one:

```
sum(any(x < y for y in arr[i:]) for i,x in enumerate(arr)) # answer is 3
```

And if you want to count the number of exact such pairs (like what your actual code seems to be doing):

```
sum(x < y for i,x in enumerate(arr) for y in arr[i:]) # answer is 4
```

Comment: Hello. I meant followed by a greater number at any later index. So in the example list [6,1,2,7], 6 is followed 1 time by a greater number 1 is followed 2 times by a greater number , 2 is followed 1 time by a greater number (1+2+1=4). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use map to get the list of True/False for each pair of number in the list depending on the condition if x < y. This list is being generated using the for loop. After getting the list, filter the number of 'True' in the list. Then create a single list using itertools.chain.from_iterable() function and find its length.

```
import itertools

arr = [6, 1, 2, 7]
num = len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list(filter(lambda x: x , map(lambda x, y: x<y, arr[:-i], arr[i:]))) for i, x in enumerate(arr))))
print(num)
```